# object still exists after setting to nil

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management

I am using ARC. I have a method that runs at the end of a game I have written which should clear up memory. There are a series of objects in an `NSMutableArray`, which i remove using `removeObject:`. I then set these objects to `nil`. However, using `NSLog` on these objects shows that they still exist. Why does setting them to `nil` not remove them from memory?

Comment: reset your device and then check it

Comment: ARC doesn't promise to release the memory at the very moment. It sends message to the OS "I dont need that memory, if you need, you can take"

Comment: @AnoopVaidya that isn't correct at all. ARC is a compile time memory management system. It re-inserts the calls to release, dealloc etc at compile time so you don't have to write them in yourself. What you are talking about in your comment is Garbage Collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ARC (automatic reference counting), setting a reference to an object to `nil` means two different things depending on the kind of reference you are nil-ing:

1. If it is a `strong` reference, then nil-ing it means decreasing the reference count of the referenced object;
2. if it is a `weak` reference, nil-ing it does nothing.

Thus, nil-ing can lead to different outcomes. Specifically, it is only when the reference count goes to zero that the object is deallocated. This would correspond to a case where no other object in the system is *owning* the first one (which means holding a `strong` reference to it).

So, in your case there could be either some other objects keeping a `strong` reference to the objects you try to `nil`; or, you might be nil-ing a weak reference. If you show some code, it may become clearer.

Comment: This is very helpful, but then how does one go about freeing the memory, if a weak reference does nothing and a strong reference lowers the retain count?

Comment: a weak reference does not either increment the retain count, so if you have a local (stack) variable holding a weak reference, it behaves like an autorelease object and it will be deallocated at the next run loop iteration (through the auto release pool mechanism). In your case, you should look for another `strong` reference pointing to the same object and get rid of that.